# How can I remove repeated characters but leave two of them?

Tags: regex, perl, string

If there are more than 2 characters
"Hiiiiiii
My frieeend!!!!!!!"

I need to be reduced to 
"Hii
My frieend!!"

Please undestand that in my language there are many words with double chars.
Thnx in advance

kplla

Comment: It depends on language/platform. Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Will you be using Regex or not?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl / regex (and if it's not english, Perl has given me better luck with Unicode than PHP):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$str = "Hiiiiii My Frieeeeend!!!!!!!";

$str =~ s/(.)\1\1+/$1$1/g;

print $str;
```

Comment: \1\1+ is equivalent to \1{2,} (2 or more of the first capture)

Comment: kixx: you're right; that might be cleaner. 
brian: wow, first time I got the code correct enough and all you had to do was edit my capitalization! I feel proud. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If a `PHP` and `regex` based solution is fine you can do:

```
$str = "Hiiiiiii My frieeend!!!!!!!";
```

<s>`$str = preg_replace('#(.)\1+#','$1',$str);

    echo $str; // prints Hi My friend!`</s>

```
$str = preg_replace('#(.)\1{2,}#','$1$1',$str);
echo $str; // prints Hii My frieend!!
```

You can make use of the `regex` used above in `Perl` too:

```
$str = "Hiiiiiii My frieeend!!!!!!!";
$str =~s/(.)\1{2,}/$1$1/g;
```

Comment: note the OP wants the output "Hii My frieend!!" -- so this isn't quite right yet.

Comment: I believe the request was to leave doubles but not more than doubles, right?

Comment: Yes Devin. No more than doubles. My language is brazillian. (sorry) I forgot to tell you but I need in perl.(sorry again) The idea is to reduce to no more than 2. This way I´m allowing people to express their "feelings" and I´ll not destroy words that have double chars. thnx

Comment: @kplla: while I appreciate the effort to reduce this kind of writing, I have to tell you that you'll be fighting your users here. They **will** find a way to work around your filter (for example "Hii.ii.ii.ii.ii My friee.eend!!.!!") and they will have a lot of endurance in finding ways around such filters.

Comment: But they are children (for now) and they will stop as they see something that cuts their idea back. In the future I´ll have to work it better... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another regex solution that uses lookahead (just for fun), in Java:

```
System.out.println(
    "Hiiiiii My Frieeeeend!!!!!!!".replaceAll("(.)(?=\\1\\1)", "")
); // prints "Hii My Frieend!!"
```